# Explain assigning address of an array to Array of pointer variable

Tags: arrays, c

```
int main ()
{
   

 int a[4]={1,5,7,3};
   
 
//here i have assigned  address directly to array of pointer variable p

int *p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3}; //no error whatsoever with this declaration
    
printf("%u %u %d",p,*p,*(*p));
    
printf("\n %u ",&a);//just checking the value for the array variable a
    
//however when i assign value to the array of pointer variable
   
 p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};//<- this gives an error stating expected expression before '{' token
}
```

Comment: Initialization is *not* actually an assignment. This: `int *p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};` is initialization of an array, and is allowed; this: `p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};` is attempting to assign an array, which is not allowed.

Comment: Better learn C#. C lang requires different way of thinking.

Comment: @Adrian Mole **PSA to Python Users:** Initialization is *not* actually assignment in Computer Science ...

Answer (score 0):

`int *p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};` declares a pointer to an array of size 4 and initializes it with the 4 elements of the array `a`. I don't see the need for a *pointer to an array* here, but it's not wrong.

`p[4]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3};` is invalid C syntax, hence the vague error description. Perhaps you were trying to do one of the following?

```
*p = a; // Let 'p' point to the array with the name 'a'.
```

or, e.g.,

```
*p[3] = 5; // Set the last element (i.e. index 3) of the array pointed to by 'p' to 5.
```

or, e.g.,

```
*p[1] = a[2]; // Set the element with index 1 of 'p' to the element with index 2 of 'a'.
```

On a side note, some of the format specifiers used in `printf` are incorrect.